# DrawHighlight() in Coded UI can not work in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to make an automation script (not for testing purpose) using Coded UI, that works in Console Application.

This webpage helped me quite much. 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/07/15/running-codedui-test-from-another-application/

However, if I use DrawHighlight(), I will get below exception

System.InvalidOperationException:{"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."}

I did some research on this exception, and all the solutions are for WPF or winform app, and I can not make it work for me.

My program is below:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 10000;
            Playback.Initialize();
            var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("https://www.google.com/");
            HtmlEdit uIGoogleEdit = new HtmlEdit(browser);
            uIGoogleEdit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Name, "q");
            uIGoogleEdit.DrawHighlight();
            //......(do something here)......
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a piece of code that I ever tried, but not working(replacing "uIGoogleEdit.DrawHighlight()" in above):

```
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate ()
        {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(delegate ()
                    {
                        uIGoogleEdit.DrawHighlight();
                    }));
        }));

        myThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        myThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself: add [STAThread] before the Main function, then the code works.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
```